# Internal structure of combined key Indexing in SQL

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

After reading [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work) answer on Indexing of tables, a doubt came up. Think we have a table with two columns and neither is unique but the combination. SO if I add a unique key like this, `UNIQUE KEY (col1,col2)` then how would the internal index file look like? I mean will it keep two separate b-trees or one single B-tree and if only one B-tree is made, then what would be the structure ?

And if my queries will be only on **col1**, then will this indexing be useful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

This should answer both questions.